# Which of the following are recursive formulas for the nth term of the following geometric sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{3}{4}, 1, \frac{4}{3}, \frac{16}{9}....$$

Please could someone help me, I've been stuck on this question all night.

P.S. I'm $13$.

Comment: As an addition to Brian's answer below, for any geometric sequence with first term $x_1=a\in\Bbb C$ and common ratio $r\in\Bbb C$, we have the explicit closed for the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ term as $x_n=ar^{n-1}~\forall~n\geq 2$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Each term is $\frac43$ times the previous term. Can you convert that into a recursive description of the form $a_{n+1}=\text{ some function of }a_n$?

Answer (score 0):

The general formula of  geometric series is given by $ar^{n-1}$ so here $a=\frac{3}{4}$and $r=\frac{4}{3}$ hence the general formula would be $\frac{3}{4}\frac{4^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}$ which  is equal to  $\frac{9}{16}\frac{4^n}{3^n}$ where $n$ is the number of term basically $t_n$. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Each term is simply the previous term multiplied by $\frac{4}{3}$.  In other words:

$a_n=\frac{4}{3}a_{n-1}$

And that is a recursive series that fits your sequence.